# Difference between iphone 5s and iphone 6(tcp)

Tags: ios, iphone, tcp, inputstream, handler

Is there any difference between iPhone 5s and iPhone 6 in `TCP connection`?
I've run the same `tcp` code in 5s and 6, and in 6 is working fine, but 5s suddenly stop while getting data.
When code running stop, event handler not working neither.
iOS version in two devices are same to 12.1.4.

**init code**

```
CFStreamCreatePairWithSocketToHost(kCFAllocatorDefault,
                                   (__bridge CFStringRef) serverip,
                                    serverport,
                                    & _readStream,
                                    & _writeStream);

 self.inputStream = (__bridge NSInputStream *)self.readStream;
 [self.inputStream setDelegate:self];
 [self.inputStream scheduleInRunLoop:[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] forMode:NSRunLoopCommonModes];

 self.outputStream = (__bridge NSOutputStream *)self.writeStream;
 [self.outputStream setDelegate:self];
 [self.outputStream scheduleInRunLoop:[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] forMode:NSRunLoopCommonModes];

 [self.inputStream open];
 [self.outputStream open];
```

**event handler code**

```
else if(eventCode == NSStreamEventHasBytesAvailable)
{
    if([aStream isEqual: self.inputStream])
    {
        NSInteger len = 0;
        uint8_t buf[4096];
        len = [self.inputStream read:buf maxLength:4096];

        if(len > 0)
        {
            NSMutableData* data = [[NSMutableData alloc] initWithLength:0];
            [data appendBytes: (const void *)buf length:len];
            [file_handler writeData:data];

            len_read = len_read + (int)len;

            if(len_read >= file_length) // download complete
            {
                @synchronized (self)
                {
                    [self.inputStream close];
                    [self.inputStream removeFromRunLoop:[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] forMode:NSRunLoopCommonModes];
                    [self.inputStream setDelegate:nil];
                    self.inputStream = nil;

                    [self.outputStream close];
                    [self.outputStream removeFromRunLoop:[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] forMode:NSRunLoopCommonModes];
                    [self.outputStream setDelegate:nil];
                    self.outputStream = nil;
```

Comment: Pls show code or error.

Comment: @Lumialxk here!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why it have difference between 5s and 6 yet.

But I solve this problem by setting socket receive buffer size.